# Google Drive REST API Windows Forms login

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rest, google-drive-api

I'm having a problem retrieving the access token from the redirect uri. When I try my coded procedure on my mozilla I get redirected to my localhost with the access token, but how do I instantiate this with my webBrowser in C#?
My current code looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string client_id = "CLIENT_ID";
    public string client_secret= "CLIENT_SECRET";
    public string redirect_uri = "http://localhost:5050";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
        webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
        webBrowser.Navigate(String.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=email+profile&redirect_uri={0}&client_id={1}&hl=de&from_login=1&as=d832bdaf61552d&pli=1&authuser=0"
            ,redirect_uri, client_id));

    }

    void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;
        //MessageBox.Show(wb.Url.ToString());
        if (wb.Url.ToString().StartsWith("http://localhost"))
        {

            String[] s = wb.Url.ToString().Split('=');
            string authCode = s[s.Length - 1];

            MessageBox.Show("auth Code: " + authCode);

            //WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            //var data = new NameValueCollection();
            //data["code"] = authCode;
            //data["client_id"] = client_id;
            //data["client_secret"] = client_secret;
            //data["redirect_uri"] = "http://localhost:5050";
            //data["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";

            //var response = wc.UploadValues("accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "POST", data);

            //foreach (byte a in response)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
            //}
        }
    }
```

If you know how to do this with the GoogleDrive API please share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

Please Use UIWebBrowser instead of WebBrowser and your code should like this.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    UIWebBrowser.AllowNavigation = true;
    UIWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
    UIWebBrowser.Navigate(String.Format("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=email+profile&redirect_uri={0}&client_id={1}&hl=de&from_login=1&as=d832bdaf61552d&pli=1&authuser=0"
        ,redirect_uri, client_id));

}

void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("http://localhost"))
     {
            // Redirect so we end up with a blank web browser control
            UIWebBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");

           code = e.Url.Query;


    }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between a WebBrowser and a UI WebBRows

Comment: *UIWebBrowser. And which assembly do I have to add

Comment: in asp.net 4.0 it comes with system.windows.forms and this will included automatically when creates new windows form.

Comment: I dont use asp.net I use .NET. Its a client Application.
I dont even get redirected to my localhost. I get redirected to an uri that looks like this: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=RSTUFFd&hl=de&pageId=none&xsrfsign=STUFF" that is my Problem